# How do I round up or down to the nearest hour/minute/second?

Tags: powerquery, m

In PowerQuery, how can I round up/down to the nearest hour/minute/second?

I can't find any suitable functions available in any of these locations on Microsoft:

- [Time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/time-functions)
- [DateTime functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-functions)
- [Date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions)

I've also found some other resources here, but they don't perfectly help me:

- [Round time to nearest 15 min with Power Query](https://curbal.com/curbal-learning-portal/round-time-to-nearest-15-min-with-power-query)
- [Rounding datetimes to nearest minute or hour in Power Query](https://apexinsights.net/blog/rounding-datetimes)
- [Round time DOWN to the nearest 5/15/30 minutes](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Round-time-DOWN-to-the-nearest-5-15-30-minutes/td-p/311676)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually in converting the Date/Time value to a Number value, then rounding that one, then converting back again.

I've written the below function to do this rounding process automatically. It includes the flexibility to round to different time intervals (`hour`, `minute`, `second`), and different rounding values (`5`, `15`, `60`, etc), and also to be able to round in different directions (`up`, `down`).

```fs
let
  fun_RoundTime =
    ( DateTimeToRound as any
    , optional TimeInterval as text
    , optional RoundingInterval as number
    , optional RoundingDirection as text
    ) as time =>
      let
      
        /* Notes:
          - 'TimeInterval' should be one of: 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second'.
          - 'RoundingInterval' is for rounding to nearest minute, nearest 5 minutes, nearest 15 minutes, etc...
          - 'RoundingDirection' should be one of: 'Up', 'Down', 'Nearest' or 'null'. If 'null', it will default to 'Nearest'.
        */

        // Validate 'TimeInterval'
        tmp_TimeInterval = 
          if List.Contains({null, ""}, TimeInterval) then Text.Proper("Minute")
          else if List.Contains({"Hour","Minute","Second"}, Text.Proper(TimeInterval)) then Text.Proper(TimeInterval)
          else error "'TimeInterval' must be one of: 'Hour','Minute','Second'. No other values are accepted.",

        // Validate 'RoundingDirection'
        tmp_RoundingDirection =
          if List.Contains({null, ""}, RoundingDirection) then "Nearest"
          else if List.Contains({"Up","Down","Nearest"}, Text.Proper(RoundingDirection)) then Text.Proper(RoundingDirection)
          else error "'RoundingDirection' must be one of: 'Up','Down','Nearest' or 'null'.",

        // Set source
        Source = DateTimeToRound,

        // Make function round to nearest minute by default
        Rounding =
          if List.Contains({null, ""}, RoundingInterval) then 1
          else RoundingInterval,
        
        // Convert datetime to decimal: Convert to number of days since 30/12/1899. Decimal component stores the time component of the datetime
        TimeDecimal = Number.From(Source),
        
        // Convert number from representing days to representing minutes. Default rounding is to the minute.
        TimeConverted = 
          if tmp_TimeInterval = "Hour" then TimeDecimal * (24 / Rounding)
          else if tmp_TimeInterval = "Minute" then TimeDecimal * (24 * 60 / Rounding)
          else if tmp_TimeInterval = "Second" then TimeDecimal * (24 * 60 * 60 / Rounding)
          else TimeDecimal * (24 * 60 / Rounding),

        // Round it
        RoundedTime =
          if tmp_RoundingDirection = "Nearest" then Number.Round(TimeConverted)
          else if tmp_RoundingDirection = "Up" then Number.RoundUp(TimeConverted)
          else if tmp_RoundingDirection = "Down" then Number.RoundDown(TimeConverted)
          else Number.Round(TimeConverted),
        
        // Convert back to days since 30/12/1899
        TimeConvertedBack = 
          if tmp_TimeInterval = "Hour" then RoundedTime / (24 / Rounding)
          else if tmp_TimeInterval = "Minute" then RoundedTime / (24 * 60 / Rounding)
          else if tmp_TimeInterval = "Second" then RoundedTime / (24 * 60 * 60 / Rounding)
          else RoundedTime / (24 * 60 / Rounding),

        // Finalise
        TimeFinal = Time.From(TimeConvertedBack)
    
      in
        TimeFinal
in
  fun_RoundTime
```

You can check it by running any of these functions:

```fs
fun_RoundTime(Time.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))
fun_RoundTime(Time.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), "minute", 15)
fun_RoundTime(Time.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), "hour", 2, "down")
```

For more information, you should check out this helpful GitHub repo: [PowerBI-Helpers](https://github.com/chrimaho/powerbi-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

I have a tried and tested solution. For example I have the following times in a column: 07:52:00 and 08:09:00. With general rules I need to round the former up and the latter down.

My logic was - if I can extract the minute from each of the time values that would indicate whether I should round up or down e.g. if the minute is 30 or greater round up and if the minute is less than 30 round down.

I created a custom column and used the Time function in M along with conditionals as follows:

= `if Time.Minute([Time-Col]) >= 30 then Time.EndOfHour([Time-Col]) else Time.StartOfHour([Time-Col])`

So essentially if the time needs to be rounded up the Time.EndOfHour function will return the hour that is approaching. However, if the time needs to be rounded down the Time.StartOfHour function will return the hour that has already commenced.

Hope that makes sense and of course let me know if my proposition is actually flawed lol :)